# ios6 web app delete privacy setting

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iphone-web-app

I'm developing a web app and testing on my iPhone 5 running iOS6.

The app was running as a home screen app and during use requested access to the camera roll on the phone which I allowed, this has added a toggle in settings > privacy > photos on the phone for my web app.

I've since abandoned this web app and deleted the home screen icon but the toggle still shows in the privacy settings, I'd like to remove this toggle but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there are profile for it under Settings/General/Profiles?

Comment: Found the answer....

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

Removes everything but that does the job!